# Rails Relationship Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which holds social networks. ie (twitter, facebook, ...). I then need to have the user model and company model both has_many socials. Would I need to use the has_many :through relationship ie.

- A User can have many socials
- A Company can have many socials
- And Socials belongs to users and companies

Would something like this be right?

```
class Social < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :social_networks
  has_many :socials, : through => :social_networks
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :social_networks
  has_many :socials, : through => :social_networks
end
```

Would I need to have the Model SocialNetworks ?

Then I would have 2 join table:

socials_users & companies_socials

Would this be the right way to do it ?

I don't think the easier has_and_belongs_to_many would work for this ?

Hope some one can shed some light on the right way to do this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing there is no problem using HABTM ie.

```
class Social < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :socials
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :socials
end
```

Then create the 2 joining tables

socials_users & companies_socials